# Grails...send/save table data on click of a button

Tags: grails

I have a Grails project and I need to send/save table data. I have a controller(doesn't have views) with following code.

```
class JsonController {

def getCompany = {
    for (String s in request.getHeaderNames()) {

        println request.getHeader(s)
    }
    println Company.list()
    render Company.list() as XML
}

def getEmployees = {
    for (String s in request.getHeaderNames()) {

        println request.getHeader(s)
    }
    render Employees.list() as XML
}

def getManagers = {
    for (String s in request.getHeaderNames()) {

        println request.getHeader(s)
    }
    render Managers.list() as XML
}
}
```

Now I need to call/run these functions on clicking an link and send the output thru email or save to a folder. How can I do this?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the following code requires the [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail)

I would move your `JsonController` to a service, which I renamed to `XMLService`, since that is what you are returning.  Then, inject the `XMLService` in whatever artefacts you want to use it in, such as another service or controller.

```
import grails.converters.XML;

class XMLService {

  def getCompanies = {
    return Company.list() as XML
  }

  def getEmployees = {
    return Employees.list() as XML
  }

  def getManagers = {
    return Managers.list() as XML
  }
}
```

Then, in a controller or service. This example uses a service:

```
  class MyMailingService {  

    def mailService  //<-- included from the Mail plugin
    def xmlService

    void sendEmployeeList(){
      mailService.sendMail {
        to "fred@g2one.com","ginger@g2one.com"
        subject "Hello to mutliple recipients"
        body xmlService.getEmployees()
      }
    }

  }
```

And for storing files, something like the following.  Note, that this does not have to be service, but for demonstration purposes, it was easier.

```
  class MyStorageService {  

    def xmlService

    void storeEmployeeList(){
      //It was a little unclear how you wanted to store the file, so be careful because this this does not include checks you would want to implement in production (e.g. checks for existing files, possible runtime exceptions, etc).
      def f= new File('employees.txt') //see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN2015-Files
      f << xmlService.getEmployees()
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Noticed you have had answers for email text file - this is how to to store to XML file
where rowid will be the definition for each xml row

> ```
> def file=""${System.properties['catalina.base']}/file.xml" 
> try {
>           new File(file).withWriter { writer ->
>
>           def xml = new MarkupBuilder( writer )
>           def Users = Registeration.list()
>           xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")
>           xml.rowid {
>             Employees.each { employee ->
>                xml.registeration(id: employee.id) {
>                                    username(employee.username)
>                                    //somethingelse(employee.somethingelse)
>               }
>                }
>            }
>              }
>
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           result=e.printStackTrace()
>       }
>       if (result!=null) { 
>            result="all done stored in "+file
>       }else{
>           result="Something has gone wrong with "+file
>       }
> ```